# PHP Curl GET request not returning same as in browser

Tags: curl, php-5.6

Having trouble getting the same data using PHP curl as when I use the same url in a browser.

This is my curl request.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Basic " . $authString));
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

I can't use file_get_contents due to the authorization required.

Part of the returned data is a url that should have this query string:

```
?q=StatusDate%20%3C%20 ... &fields= ...
```

which decoded is

```
?q=StatusDate <  ... &fields= ...
```

And that's what I get when I use a browser.  But when I use PHP and Curl, I only get this:

```
?q=StatusDate&fields= ...
```

The `%20%3C%20 ...` is missing.

I'm guessing I need another curlopt setting, but can't see anything obvious.  The returned data is in json format and using `json_decode` on it makes no difference.

I've tried `CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER` which is ignored by my version of PHP according to the manual and it made no difference.

Help me out somebody please.

I'm using php 5.6.30

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the browser's user-agent string with your curl request (if you think it works on browser). You can do this by either of the way:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/600.7.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.7 Safari/600.7.12");
```

Or,

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
    array("Authorization: Basic " . $authString,
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/600.7.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.7 Safari/600.7.12')
);
```

May be a typo, I can see an extra `)` at your code where you are setting http-header.

Comment: It works in firefox, chrome and IE.  What user agent would I specify?  The typo is just me copy pasting to this site incorrectly - now fixed.

Comment: It should work with any user-agent. See which one works (if).

Comment: I gave up on this in the end and approached it completely differently as nothing worked.  Thanks anyway Sabuj.